# Google Apps Script (Google Docs) - trigger on comment add or change?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am searching thorugh **Google Apps Script documentation** and I don't find how to make a trigger if **comment is added or changed** in a google document.
Under ElementType section (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type) I can see a property COMMENT_SECTION but also there is **CommentSection** element crossed in the description of the property. Does this mean that CommentSection class doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the comments of a document you need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (which you should enable in the Script Editor by selecting Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console. [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services))

Once enabled, you can retrieve the comments with the [Drive.Comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list). The list of properties of the comments can are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments).

Here's an example:

```
function retrieveComments() {
  var comments;
    comments = Drive.Comments.list('docId');
    if (comments.items && comments.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < comments.items.length; i++) {
        var comment = comments.items[i];
        Logger.log('%s on %s by %s', comment.content, comment.createdDate, comment.author.displayName);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No comments found.');
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you can store the `commentId`, `createdDate` and `modifiedDate` to evaluate if the have changed

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for!